# Use either window title or process name

Tags: c#

I'm working on a windows handler I am newish to C# I have most of the code done but I can not seem to figure out how to make it so you could use either window's title like it is currently or the process name like e.g "notepad". I tried a for each loop but then it would try to change my static main to IntPtr main.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TP_WinState
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            String window = args[0];

            Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                { "Hide", 0 },
                { "Show Normal", 1 },
                { "Show Minimized", 2 },
                { "Show Maximized", 3 },
                { "Show Active", 4 },
                { "Restore", 9 },
                { "Show Default", 10 },
                { "Close", 98 },
                { "Force Close", 99 }
            };

            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, window);
            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) { Console.WriteLine("Window not found"); return; }


            if (!Int32.TryParse(args[1], out int nCmdShow))
                nCmdShow = dictionary[args[1]];

            if (nCmdShow > 10)
            {
                UInt32 message = 0x0000;
                switch (nCmdShow)
                {
                    case 98:
                        message = 0x0010; break;
                    case 99:
                        message = 0x0002; break;
                    default: break;
                }
                SendMessage(hWnd, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            else
                ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, nCmdShow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " I tried a for each loop but then it would try to change my static main to IntPtr main." can you please share more details?

Comment: ```IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(window))
                {
                    hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
                }
            }
            return hWnd;```

i tried to do something like this but that doesn't seem to be working right and gave me error on return and tried to make "static Void Main(string[] args)" to "static IntPtr Main(string[] args)"

Comment: oh, Main should remain void or int at all times, "return" returns value from method. I guess you just copy-pasted it from somewhere, instead of return just store value in some variable (remove line with return and you will get your handle in hWnd) or make a new method which will return IntPtr. I recommend to finish some basic programming course first